# Takeuchi numbers in Clojure (performance)

Tags: performance, algorithm, clojure

When computing [Takeuchi numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TAKFunction.html), we need to figure out the number of times the function calls itself. I quickly came up with:

```
(def number (atom 0))

(defn tak [x y z]
  (if (<= x y)
    y
    (do 
      (dosync (swap! number inc))
      (tak (tak (dec x) y z)
           (tak (dec y) z x)
           (tak (dec z) x y)))))

(defn takeuchi_number [n]
  (dosync (reset! number 0))
  (tak n 0 (inc n))
  @number)

(time (takeuchi_number 10))
; 1029803
; "Elapsed time: 11155.012266 msecs"
```

But the performance is really bad. How to make it blazingly fast in Clojure ?

Comment: do you need this as a metric for the calls to that function in its lifetime or do you want to have this number with the result?  for the later this appropach would be wrong (concurrent calls) and passing it along (e.g. as a meta) would be better.

Comment: Dropping the `dosync`- which you do not need for swapping atoms - increases runtime for me by factor 5.

Comment: I meant DEcreases ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone says, removing the dosync seems to improve things by a factor of 10, but that isn't the whole story. Once the JVM has hotspotted your code it gets a further factor of 10 faster. This is why you should be using criterium or similar to test real-world speed...

```
(def number (atom 0))

(defn tak [x y z]
  (if (<= x y)
    y
    (do 
      (swap! number inc)
      (tak (tak (dec x) y z)
           (tak (dec y) z x)
           (tak (dec z) x y)))))

(defn takeuchi_number [n]
  (reset! number 0)
  (tak n 0 (inc n))
  @number)

;=> (time (takeuchi_number 10))
; "Elapsed time: 450.028 msecs"
; 1029803
;=> (time (takeuchi_number 10))
; "Elapsed time: 42.008 msecs"
; 1029803
```

Original with dosync was about 5s on my machine, so we're two orders of base 10 magnitude up already! Is this the best we can do? Let's refactor to pure functions and get away from the counter.

```
(defn tak [c x y z]
  (if (<= x y)
    [c y]
    (let [[a- x-] (tak 0 (dec x) y z)
          [b- y-] (tak 0 (dec y) z x)
          [c- z-] (tak 0 (dec z) x y)]
      (recur (+' 1 a- b- c- c) x- y- z-))))

(defn takeuchi_number [n]
   (tak 0 n 0 (inc n)))

;=> (time (takeuchi_number 10))
; "Elapsed time: 330.741 msecs"
; [1029803 11]
;=> (time (takeuchi_number 10))
; "Elapsed time: 137.829 msecs"
; [1029803 11]
;=> (time (takeuchi_number 10))
; "Elapsed time: 136.866 msecs"
; [1029803 11]
```

Not as good. The cost of holding the state in the vector and passing it around is likely an overhead. However, now we've refactored to purity, let's take advantage of our good behaviour!

```
=> (def tak (memoize tak))
#'euler.tak/tak
=> (time (takeuchi_number 10))
"Elapsed time: 1.401 msecs"
[1029803 11]
```

A healthy 3000 or so times faster. Works for me.

Comment: Easy exercise for the reader: why isn't there any point me running the last test twice and claiming "Elapsed time: 0.055 msecs"? :-)

Comment: I am actually so impressed, by the speed of the memoize-d one. Have you tried it for big numbers ?

Comment: Maybe also try force: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/force#example-542692cdc026201cdc326ce9

Answer (score 1):

A purely functional way of implementing this would be for your `tak` function to return a pair `[result count]`, where `result` is the actual result of the `tak` computation and `count` is the number of times the function recursively called itself. But in this case, I think that would cause all sorts of painful contortions in the body of the function and wouldn't be worth it.

The usage of `atom` here, while idiomatic Clojure, imposes unnecessary overhead; it's really targeted at synchronizing independent updates to shared state between threads. Basically what you want is a mutable object you can pass around to recursive function calls in the same thread, with no synchronization required. An array should be sufficient for that purpose:

```
(defn tak [x y z ^longs counter]
  (if (<= x y)
    y
    (do 
      (aset counter 0 (inc (aget counter 0)))
      (tak (tak (dec x) y z counter)
           (tak (dec y) z x counter)
           (tak (dec z) x y counter)
           counter))))

(defn takeuchi_number [n]
  (let [counter (long-array [0])]
    (tak n 0 (inc n) counter)
    (aget counter 0)))
```

Note that I've moved the counter definition from being a global constant to being a parameter on the helper function, to ensure that the mutable state is only used locally within that function.

Comment: I tried it but it did not perform as fast as I thought.  Making the function itself functional as you did it was certainly the first right move though. Thanks !